# How to determine if a function is smooth?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, derivatives, smooth-functions

I want to figure out whether or not the following function is "Smooth".
As far as I understand, a smooth function is means that it is C^∞

But how do I go about it with this function:

Let f : [0, π] → R^2 defined by f(t) = (sin(t)^2, cos2(t)^2).

Is f smooth?

Answer (score 2):

Since each component is a $C^\infty$ function, $f$ is a $C^\infty$ function.

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong function, please check again. The sin and cos are squared!

Comment: In which way does that affect my answer?

Comment: Hmm good point. I'm just confused now because my professor said it was not smooth  because f '(0) = 0. I don't understand his reasoning, that's why I posted here. Is he wrong then?

Comment: My guess is that your professor said that $f$ is not *regular*.

Comment: No he did say smooth. Also he said that for f to be smooth, we require that the vector f ' (x) is non-null for every x. Is this a false statement?

Comment: When we deal with curves (and $f$ is a curve), we say that a point $a$ of the domain is *singular* if $f'(a)=0$ and *regular* otherwise. And we say that $f$ is regular if the domain has no singular points. So, your $f$ is *not* regular, but it *is* smooth.